# Gambler's ruin limit question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A gambler plays a series of games, where she wins each game with probability $.5$ and loses each game with probability $.5.$ If she bets $c$ and wins, her wealth increases by $2c$. If she bets $c$ and loses, her wealth decreases by $c.$ She begins with $W_0 = 100$ and bets a fraction $r$ of her assets each game. Let $W_n$ be her wealth after $n$ games. Find
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log W_n}{n}.$$

I am very confused on this question because I do not know how to give a formula for $W_n.$ Can anyone give me any help?

Comment: Your introduction says what happens to $W_n$ at each step.  You might find it worth translating that into what happens to $\log W_n$ at each step.

Comment: @Henry Do I need to use indicator variables?

Comment: I would say $W_{n+1}=W_n(1+2r)$ with probability $\frac12$ and $=W_n(1-r)$ also with probability $\frac12$.  Translate that to  $\log W_{n+1}= \log W_n +\log(1+2r)$ or $= \log W_n +\log(1-r)$.  So $\log W_n$ is $\log W_0$ plus $n$ samples of a random variable taking the values $\log(1+2r)$ or $\log(1-r)$ with equal probability.  So this starts looking like the law of large numbers or central limit theorem